# Passing php variables to javascript in laravel syntax errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Question 1)
When passing PHP variables to be used in javascript if the variables hold an array, it will result in an error relating to the attempted conversion of array to string when trying to pass these values in the following manner. Why do I have to json encode the value before it works when $var itself is already an array?

PHP Code

```
$var = ['test'];
```

Javascript

```
Let var = {!!$var!!};
```

Solution

```
Let var = {!!json_encode($var)!!}
```

Question 2 when passing PHP variables that may have the value of null to javascript, it may result in a syntax error. For example,

PHP Code

```
$var = null;
```

Javascript

```
Let var = {{$var}};
```

Error

```
Var = ; (Syntax error)
```

Failed Solution

```
if({{$var}}){
    let var = {{$var}};
```

Solution

```
Let var = '{{$var');
```

Why does my attempted solution of only setting the value of the var when $var has a value fails?

Comment: "Passing" variables from PHP to Javascript in this manner is more accurately "writing out valid Javascript using PHP".  Why did failed solution fail?  Because the result, when $var contains no value, is `if () { ... }` which is not valid javascript.  You could do the `if` part entirely in php, and only write the variable when the if condition passes.

Comment: What do the `!!` mean in Javascript? Have never seen that before.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware `{!! !!}` is Blade syntax for outputting PHP variables as-is.

Comment: You might have success by outputting the variable as JSON.

Comment: A PHP value is a null or empty value, which doesn't exactly translate well when outputting to the screen, or javascript in this case.  Using json_encode will ensure that the variables are properly escaped and translated to javascript.

Comment: `Let var = ...` will never work in javascript because `var` is a keyword just like let. You can not name a variable `var`

Comment: @aynber Ah, yes, that makes sense. It's not Javascript. I was just reading plain PHP, which it is not.

Comment: PHP has no automatic mechanism to convert an array into a string representation. If you tried to output an array using `echo`, that would only get you the literal _word_ `Array` as result. And blade probably doesn't have anything specifically for that either (hence you get it complaining about array to string conversion.) Plus, there simply _is_ no "generic" way to convert an array into a string, that would match _all_ possible scenarios. You want to create valid JavaScript out of your array here, so use the quickest thing available for that - which is `json_encode`.

Answer (score 0):

simply put laravel echo in doouble quote

```
<script>
 let var1="{{$var}}";
</script>
```